# Hardhat coverage tests failure - Stack too deep

Tags: solidity, hardhat, solc, compilation

I got my smart contracts ready over [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) and once I'm running `hh test` all the tests are passing successfully but while running `hh coverage` I'm getting the below error.

Any idea why the regular tests are working but the coverage isn't?

How can this be solved?

```
Version
=======
> solidity-coverage: v0.7.20

Instrumenting for coverage...
=============================

> MyContract1.sol
> MyContract2.sol
> MyContract3.sol


Compilation:
============

Compiling 35 files with 0.8.6
CompilerError: Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly: Variable headStart is 1 slot(s) too deep inside the stack.


Error in plugin solidity-coverage: HardhatError: HH600: Compilation failed
```

Comment: Stack too deep often appears when function is taking too may variables, or some structure has enormous amount of variables inside of it)

Comment: Thanks you. I still think there's more to it since regular tests are working well while coverage fails

Comment: Yeah, that is strange. You might report that issue to the team behind HardHat. (I think you can go to their GitHub to do that.)

Answer (score 4):

Add `.solcover.js` at the root of your project folder with the following option:

```
module.exports = {
  configureYulOptimizer: true
};
```

Take a look at these related threads:

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11638#issuecomment-1101524130
https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage/blob/master/HARDHAT_README.md#configuration

Comment: Enabling yul in hardhat.config.js with details: {yul: true} worked for me but I have no idea what it does. Can you provide any explanations?